# Why is nslookup on windows so slow?

Tags: windows, dns, nslookup

I have always noticed that nslookup on any windows machine is... slow.

Example in powershell:

```
Measure-Command { nslookup superuser.com } 
TotalMilliseconds : 1318.4933
```

This typically takes 1.0 to 1.5 seconds on every windows computer I have ever tried.

Meanwhile, even in high level interpreted languages (such as perl/python), I can spin up the entire interpreter, run a script do the DNS lookup, and get the result, much faster:

```
Measure-Command {perl dns.pl superuser.com}
TotalMilliseconds : 121.099
```

It seems to me that nslookup has some large delay that occurs just to start itself, because the if you use interactive mode, the lookups happen much much faster.

So I guess my question is: Why does nslookup take so long to start up and is there any way to make it quicker? It slow speed is really annoying both for manual use and use in scripts.

Comment: I ran the same command and it was just as fast as your perl run.

Comment: Have you tried watching the actual network packets being sent/received, to determine whether it's slow during startup or does it take a long time waiting for response?

Comment: (Also, if you're already using powershell, in most cases do you need nslookup at all?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This boils down to behaviour differences.

The biggest one is nslookup will append DNS suffix from the suffix list. And depending on how many you have in your config, it can take a while (3 seconds per suffix).

If you want to make it quicker, you can bypass the suffix behaviour altogether by

- Look up the FQDN instead of the shortname
- Make the FQDN an **absolute** FQDN and not a relative one ([add a trailing dot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/437787/188553))

Comment: This indeed turned out to be the answer.... On a computer with an insane number of suffixes the PC was doing 2 lookups (one for A record and one for AAAA record) for every single suffix. I had no idea about the trick of adding a trailing dot for absolute! Thanks.